# Get Keyboard Events on Jupyter Widgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I have a text box in Jupyter likes the following:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_outpu
tagInput = widgets.Text()
```

And try to get keyboard events like `Enter` using the following code:

```
tagInput.observe(handle_process_text_submit,names='value')
```

But, it catches just the value changes. what supposed to do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You want to catch the keyboard `Enter` specifically, you can use `on_submit` event such as the following:

```
def on_submit_func(sender):
    print "enter"

tagInput.on_submit(on_submit_func)
```

Comment: Fun fact: as of June 7, 2021 the on_submit method is deprecated, and observe method is suggested as a replacement for it ( it means that solution used in the question should be applied). But the observe method lacks this functionality. 
See also:
https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2446

Comment: @mc2 Thanks for your comment. It's strange!